# Equality of limits; what is going on here, logically speaking?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, logic

Normally equations do not work like $\iff$ statements. That is, if I want to prove that $\sin 2x = 2 \sin x \cos x$ I can just start from one side and show that it's equal to the other.

However, earlier I was trying to prove that if $f$ is continuous, then

$$\lim_{z \to z_0} h(f(z)) = \lim_{z \to f(z_0)}h(z)$$

In doing this problem, I felt that it's neccesary to first assume the limit on the RHS exists, and prove that the LHS exists and has the same value. Then assume that the one on the LHS exists, and prove the RHS has the same value.

What exactly is the difference between these two scenarios?

**Edit**
Suppose the limit on the $RHS$ exists and equals $L$.

Fix $\epsilon > 0$. Then there is a $\delta_1$ such that $\forall z :|z - f(z_0)| < \delta_1 \implies |h(z)-L| < \epsilon$

Because $f$ is continuous, there exists a $\delta_2$ such that $\forall z: |z-z_0|<\delta_2 \implies |f(z) - f(z_0)| < \delta_1$

Stringing these together, we have $\forall z: |z-z_0|<\delta_2 \implies |f(z) - f(z_0)| <\delta_1 \implies |h(f(z))-L| < \epsilon$.

Thus $\forall z: |z-z_0|<\delta_2 \implies |h(f(z))-L| < \epsilon$, so the limit on the $LHS$ exists and equals $L$.

Comment: There is no uncertainty concerning whether $\sin(2x)$, or $2\sin x\cos x$ exist. That's the biggest difference I can see.

Comment: @Arthur Yup me too, I was wondering weather that's the only difference

Comment: In an equation with $\sqrt{f(x)}$ or $\frac{1}{g(x)}$ you would first show that $f(x)\geq 0$ and $g(x)\neq 0$ just to prove that ehe equation means anything at all. It is the same with the limits: you need to ensure that the notation has a meaning.

Comment: So if we have the hypothesis "both limits exist" then it should be ok to just do "one directon", right?

Comment: The formulation of your rule is wrong. You must add that $f(z) \neq f(z_0)$ as $z\to z_0$ otherwise there is a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof looks OK, except for one thing (which I don't think invalidates it): when you say $|z - f(z_0)| < \delta_1 \implies |h(z)-L| < \epsilon$, what you should really be saying is $0 < |z - f(z_0)| < \delta_1 \implies |h(z)-L| < \epsilon$. But it is still only half the story: as the example in my first answer shows, the existence of the $LHS$ does not imply the existence of the $RHS$.

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying to prove is in fact false! Suppose for example that $f(z)=0$ everywhere; then $f$ is certainly continuous. But your equation reduces to
$$\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0}h(0)=\lim_{z\rightarrow 0}h(z)$$
which is to say
$$h(0)=\lim_{z\rightarrow 0}h(z)$$

But this is only true if $h$ is continuous at $0$.

Comment: Hmmm would you be willing to take a look at my short proof if I edit the question and write it? I was sure of my proof that $LHS \implies RHS$; I thought that maybe this contradicts with $RHS \implies LHS$, but seems to contradict both...have to think more about it

Comment: I've added the proof to the question if you wouldn't mind taking a look.

Comment: @ovi: you can w

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly a feedback on your proof, but it is too long for comment.

---

It is possible to have limit equations as two sided in the sense that if one of them exists as $L$ /diverges/oscillates finitely/oscillates infinitely then so does the other. My two favorite examples of such equations are as follows:

- If $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) $ exists then $$\lim_{x\to a} \{f(x)\pm g(x)\}=\lim_{x\to a} f(x) \pm\lim_{x\to a} g(x) $$
- If $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) =L\neq 0$ then $$\lim_{x\to a} f(x) g(x) =\lim_{x\to a} f(x) \cdot\lim_{x\to a} g(x) $$ This is false if $L=0$.

For substitution (the rule in your question) we have the following result

> **Theorem**: If $x = g(t)$ is an invertible function with inverse $t = h(x)$ in the deleted neighborhood of $t = b$ and $\lim\limits_{t \to b}g(t) = a, \lim\limits_{x \to a}h(x) = b$ then either both the limits $\lim\limits_{x \to a}f(x)$ and $\lim\limits_{t \to b}f(g(t))$ exist and are equal or both of them don't exist and we can write $$\lim_{x\to a} f(x) =\lim_{t\to b} f(g(t)) $$

The proofs really don't need to be written separately for each case rather in the examples quoted above a proof of one way implication can be used to prove the implication in other direction also.